# Flatten/Normalize panda dataframe

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary object. The object is nested in nature. I want to store the object in python dataframe.
The object looks like,

```
{
    "emp": [
        {
            "emp_id": 100, 
            "emp_name": "Rahul Sen",
            "address": 
            {
                "country": "india", 
                "state": "wb"
            }, 
            "contact": 
            {
                "phone": "+91 987456321", 
                "email": "example@mail.com"
            }, 
            "identity": 
            {
                "gender": "M", 
                "age": 30,
                "physique": {
                    "height": "5.6ft", 
                    "weight": 70 
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "emp_id": 200, 
            "emp_name": "Sonali Mathur",
            "address": 
            {
                "country": "india", 
                "state": "ap"
            }, 
            "contact": 
            {
                "phone": "+91 123456789", 
                "email": "sample@mail.com"
            }, 
            "identity": 
            {
                "gender": "F",
                "age": 25,
                "physique": {
                    "height": "5.2ft", 
                    "weight": 56
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The output I want is

| emp_id | emp_name | address | contact | identity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Rahul Sen | india,wb | +91 987456321,example@mail.com | M,30,5.6ft,70 |
| 200 | Sonali Mathur | india,ap | +91 123456789,sample@mail.com | M,25,5.2ft,56 |

How can I achieve this without using any inbuilt library, want to use custom python function/code.

Comment: Do you have only **one** dictionary? or a list of many?

Comment: make at least 2 lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### answer to updated question

Using [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
out = (pd
   .json_normalize(d['emp'])
   .rename(columns=lambda s: s.split('.')[0])
   .groupby(level=0, axis=1, sort=False)
   .agg(lambda x: map(','.join, x.astype(str).to_numpy().tolist()))
)
```

Output:

```
  emp_id       emp_name   address                         contact       identity
0    100      Rahul Sen  india,wb  +91 987456321,example@mail.com  M,30,5.6ft,70
1    200  Sonali Mathur  india,ap   +91 123456789,sample@mail.com  F,25,5.2ft,56
```

##### original answer

You could use:

```
d = {'id': 100, 'address-country': 'india', 'address-state': 'wb'}

df = (pd.DataFrame([d])
        .assign(address=lambda d: d.pop('address-country')+','+d.pop('address-state'))
     )
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'id': d['id'], 'address': d['address-country']+','+d['address-state']}])
```

Output:

```
    id   address
0  100  india,wb
```

If you have a list of dictionaries:

```
lst = [{'id': 100, 'address-country': 'india', 'address-state': 'wb'},
       {'id': 101, 'address-country': 'india', 'address-state': 'dl'},
       {'id': 102, 'address-country': 'india', 'address-state': 'pb'},
      ]
```

just change the above to:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(lst)
        .assign(address=lambda d: d.pop('address-country')+','+d.pop('address-state'))
     )
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'id': d['id'], 'address': d['address-country']+','+d['address-state']}
                   for d in lst])
```

Output:

```
    id   address
0  100  india,wb
1  101  india,dl
2  102  india,pb
```

Comment: The above code is working fine. But suppose I have multiple nested columns e,g, col1-1, col1-2, col2-1,col2-2, col3-1, col3-2, ......... coln-1, coln-2. Then for each case I have to write this line || df = (pd.DataFrame(lst)
        .assign(col1=lambda d: d.pop('col1-1')+','+d.pop('col1-2'))
     ) || So can we write a code which can take care of all the nested columns in a loop way

Comment: @Saptarsi yes, it depends on the exact data, please update the question with a meaningful example

Comment: Suppose my object is, {'id': 100, 'address': {'country': 'india', 'state': 'west bengal'}, 'contact': {'phone': '+91 987456321', 'email': 'example@mail.com'}, 'identity': {'gender': 'M', 'height': '5.6ft', 'weight': 70, 'age': 30}} , Then dataframe header should be id, address, contact, identity. nested values should be string concatenated with a comma separator.

Comment: The you could be interested in `pd.json_normalize(d)`, you'd have to post-process the fields but this remains to be defined. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77102773/edit) the question with all details.

Comment: I have modified the question, as requested by you.